# Eikonal Equation in Constant Gravitational Field

Tags: general-relativity

The Eikonal Equation for light in Gravitational Field is given as,

$$g^{ik}\frac{\partial \psi}{\partial x^i}\frac{\partial \psi}{\partial x^k}=0$$

where $g^{ik}$ is the metric tensor, $\psi$ is eikonal, $x^i,x^k$ are the coordinates.

The frequency of the light defined with respect to world time is given as,

$$\omega_0 = -c\frac{\partial \psi}{\partial x^0}$$

This is my question: the book says in constant gravitational field (i.e. geometric tensor is independent of world time $x^0$), the eikonal equation doesn't contain $x^0$ explicitly, so the frequency $\omega_0$ remains constant during propagation. I don't understand this statement. Why it doesn't contain $x^0$ explicitly? And consequently, why it is constant? Thanks a lot!

Comment: If you are familiar with the separation of variables in the Hamilton-Jacobi equation, here is basically the same thing. When the variable $x_0$ does not appear except for the derivative $\partial\psi/\partial x_0$, then your solution has the form $\psi(x_0,x_i) = -\omega_0 x_0+\psi_1(x_i)$, where $\omega_0$ is the "conserved momentum" $\partial\psi/\partial x_0$. Having a nonzero cross term $g_{0i}$ will make it mathematically a bit more involved, but does not change the general idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm a little unclear on what "constant gravitational field means", but it sounds like you just mean that $g^{ik}$ has no $x^0$ dependent terms (so the metric is stationary). In that case, expanding the eikonal equation component by component and inverting for $\frac{\partial{\psi}}{\partial{x^0}}$ will show that the latter does not depend on $x^0$. It will generally, of course, depend on the other coordinates.